# Easy, simple, attractive way/path/option to signup/register a new user in Joomla 3.9

Tags: joomla

I'm a volunteer for a not-for-profit project committed to conceiving a "way" to easy (considering the user audience not used to browse websites) and make attractive the registration of a new user on the home page Joomla website 3.9.

After a web search and a look in the Joomla section of the extensions on the related, I've just found that one of the possible options that meet my requirements is a free extension that enables the user to signup with a social account (Twitter, Facebook, etc.): SLogin.

I've found that the category under which I may look for a suitable extension is: Tutorial or website tour. But all of the ones I find on the web are not free.

If I was in the shoes of a user not familiar with registering a new account on a website, maybe I'd expect to find a guided procedure with popup windows or more than one webpage with plenty of information on any single step involved in the user creation.

I wonder if there is a template or extension (free) or any other option (not custom developed) that may do that job; I'm open to any suggestions based on the requirements above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the options already mentioned, I've evaluated and finally selected a Joomla template with a slideshow extension on top that repeatedly displays the required number of slides to show how to register and/or login.

One of those slides will feature two buttons that will open a modal window to register or log in.

Answer (score 0):

Try `BreezingForms` - https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/breezing-forms/

I think it allows you (even in the free version) to create custom forms, as complex as you need (multi-page, etc.) and then port them into Joomla! user creation.

You're gonna need to hunt around on their forums/support to find out how to do this exactly because it's been a long time since I've used BreezingForms.

This post on their forum has a user asking the same question and I think they answer it conclusively: https://crosstec.org/en/forums/3-breezingforms-for-joomla/123224-how-to-make-login-and-registration-forms-with-breezingforms-pro.html

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: I'm going to try it. Ty

Comment: Nickunj, if you are able to provide Joomla support, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and help the niche community to blossom.